# Returning non-predefined fields via. API with Tastypie in Django

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am using Tastypie for non-ORM data source (Amazon Dynamodb). I have gone through the official [documentation for non-ORM source](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html) and found the following code:

```
class MessageResource(Resource):
    # Just like a Django ``Form`` or ``Model``, we're defining all the
    # fields we're going to handle with the API here.
    uuid = fields.CharField(attribute='uuid')
    user_uuid = fields.CharField(attribute='user_uuid')
    message = fields.CharField(attribute='message')
    created = fields.IntegerField(attribute='created')
```

I am new to Tastypie and what I understand is that fields uuid, message, created.. which are returned by API are defined over here. Is there any way that I return those fields that are not defined here i.e. all those fields returned by the dictionary in obj_get_list or obj_get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dehydrade method. Simply add a new key to bundle.data.

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    for item in bundle.obj.iteritems():
        bundle.data["new_key"] = "new_value"
    return bundle
```